# jQuery: retain a responsive div size for an image container before fadeIn

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, fadein

I have a bit of jQuery that selects a random image from a folder and fades it in within a div on each page load. The problem is the menu div just below the image jumps up into the blank space of the image before the image fades in.

What's the best way to have the image div retain height before the image fades in? CSS to "fill" the div before the image fades in? Or load a blank .jpg before the random image fades in? (All random images are the same size 1000px width x 250px height).

*I need to retain the responsiveness of the design*, so it's possible the best solution is to preload a blank jpg and then fade in the random image.

I haven't included the image and caption arrays for simplicity, but this function outputs the image with the .randomheader class:

**jQuery:**

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.randomheader').randomImage();
    });
    </script>

<script>
(function($){

    $.randomImage = {
        defaults: {

            path: '/fullpathhere/headerimages/',

            myImages: ['image1.jpg' , 'image2.jpg' , 'image3.jpg'],

            myCaptions: ['Caption 1' , 'Caption 2' , 'Caption 3']    
        }           
    }

    $.fn.extend({
        randomImage:function(config) {
            var config = $.extend({}, $.randomImage.defaults, config); 

            return this.each(function() {
                var imageNames = config.myImages;
                var imageCaptions = config.myCaptions;
                var imageNamesSize = imageNames.length;
                var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*imageNamesSize);
                var displayImage = imageNames[randomNumber];
                var displayCaption = imageCaptions[randomNumber];
                var fullPath = config.path + displayImage;

                // Load the random image
                $(this).attr( { src: fullPath, alt: displayImage }).fadeIn('slow');

                // Load the caption
                $('#caption').html(displayCaption).fadeIn('slow');
            });
        }
    }); 
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">

    <!-- random image loads in the div below -->
    <img src="" class="randomheader" width="1000" height="250" alt="header image">
    <div id="caption"></div>

   <!-- The nav div below jumps up into the div above -->
   <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
       // nav here
   </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.randomheader {
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-top: 1.714285714rem;
}

img.randomheader {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Put a container around the image with a fixed height.  When the image fades in it's height change won't cause flow issues. The fixed dimensions of the container should prevent the flow issues.

Comment: Thanks, but that breaks the responsiveness of the design.

Comment: What's responsive here? The above image tag has dimensions specified in implicit px units (in the HTML). Responsive layout elements are typically specified in % or em. In what way is the image supposed to change when the browser is resized?

Comment: If the problem is caused by the use of `display:none` on the image, how about starting the image with an opacity of `0` rather than `display:none`, and then using `fadeIn()` or `animate({opacity:1})`?

Comment: Remove `display:none` from `img.randomheader` in CSS and change your jQuery line to `$(this).attr( { src: fullPath, alt: displayImage }).hide().fadeIn('slow');`.  Does that help?

Comment: Is the size of the random img always the same?

Comment: @dom: thanks, but no, that doesn't help. Seems like what I need to do is preload a blank 1000x250 image and then fade the random image in; there should be a way to do that in the jQuery function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@apaul34208 pretty much hit the nail on the head there... I created an example for you based on the same principle so you can see it working.

**HTML:**

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
  <div class="randomheader">
    <div class="image"><img src="" /></div>
    <span class="caption"></span>
  </div>

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    nav here
  </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.randomheader .image {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;

  /* 
  This percentage needs to be calculated
  using the aspect ratio of your image.
  Type your image width and height in this tool
  to get the aspect ration of your image:
  http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/

  In this example the Google logo was 55:19 and 
  to get the percentage you divide 19 by 55 = 0.3454
  */
  padding-bottom: 34.54%;
}

.randomheader img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}

.randomheader .caption {
  display: block;
  min-height: 1em;
}

.randomheader img,
.randomheader .caption {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.extend({

    randomImage: function(config) {
      var defaults = {},
          config = $.extend({}, defaults, config); 

      return this.each(function() {
        var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*config.myImages.length),
            image = config.myImages[randNum],
            caption = config.myCaptions[randNum],
            path = config.path + image,
            $container = $(this),
            $image = $container.find('img'),
            $caption = $container.find('.caption');

        // preload image before adding 
        // to DOM and fading it in
        $image.attr({
          src: path,
          alt: image
        }).load(function() {
          $caption.html(caption);
          $image.add($caption).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 'slow');
        });
      });
    }

  });

}(jQuery));

// on DOM ready, 
// start 'er up
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.randomheader').randomImage({
    myImages: ['logo4w.png'],
    myCaptions: ['Google logo'],
    path: 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/'
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/setEG/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for the work, but for some reason, this still breaks my responsive design. Is there a way to preload a blank 1000x250 px image in the jquery function and then fade in the random image? Ugly, yes, but that is one way to keep the responsive design. –

Comment: Shouldn't .randomheader img height be 'auto' there? And @songdogtech why preload the blank image via jquery? Can't you just include it in your html as style="opacity: 0" and just replace the image, then fade it in with animate?

Comment: @songdogtech - If you're going to use a blank image then the above isn't necessary and I'd create your image as small as it can be while maintaining the aspect ratio of the images you will be loading in (to help with performance). So if your image is 958px by 718px that's a 4:3 aspect ratio so your blank image can be 4px by 3px. Then you just set it's width to be 100% and height to auto in CSS. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Bry - no height shouldn't be auto. The element's height is determined by the bottom padding so it needs to be set to 0.

Comment: @Jenna Smith, you're right, that worked great. Thanks! Sorry for the delay in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/585xc/2/) that I made shows how this can be done. The `display:none` styling you put on the image actually removes the element from the DOM, not just hiding it. So the `nav` bar jumps up because there is actually 'nothing' there until the `fadeIn` call.

You can still have the image hidden, but you would need to either replace it with a blank element with the same height, or put it in a container like in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it breaks the responsiveness of the design. I need height:auto on the container to keep the container responsive when resizing the browser window. Or I need to swap in a blank jpg that is 250pxx1000px.

Comment: Could you give further details on exactly what is responsive? Does the image change size or something? I don't see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yea, the image changes size in response to the browser size, from the use of max-width: 100%; height: auto; So I'm thinking that a blank.jpg 1000x250 preloaded before the random image is faded in will keep the div height and width and it won't collapse before the random image is faded in. I don't know if the responsiveness can be emulated in jsfiddle, but it breaks the responsiveness of my live site.

Comment: I added some details in the question.

Comment: The min-height: 250px kills the responsiveness; that keeps the div at 250px high even when the width of the image shrinks and this leaves space below the image container.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with my content jumping down when my slide show loaded.

This is what I found- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/f9BmY/)

html

```
<div id="Container">
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="element"> <!-- add content here --> </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#Container {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

#box {
padding-top: 25%;
/* adjust % for height */
}

#element {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background:red; /* added for visibility */
}
```

It makes a great fluid place holder. Just play with the percentages to get the desired size.

I first saw this method somewhere on SO, but I think it was an adaptation of this-
http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio

Comment: Thanks for the work, but for some reason, this still breaks my responsive design. Is there a way to preload a blank 1000x250 px image in the jquery function and then fade in the random image? Ugly, yes, but that is one way to keep the responsive design.

Comment: @songdogtech Can you link to an example? Not sure how this is breaking a responsive design.